# In terminal, what is the path of my HDDs?

Tags: command-line, hard-drive

I have 2 * 500-GB HDDs.
What is the path for each of the disks?
On *OSX* I can just do:

```
$ cd /Volumes/DiskName/FooDirectory
```

How can I do that on *Ubuntu*? How can I navigate to files in a HDD using a terminal? `/dev` and `/dev/disk` are not making sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On OS X those would be the mount points.  Under Ubuntu you would want to look at `/media/USERNAME/` for those.  Though if the volume has not been mounted you could look at `/dev/disk/by-label`.

If the drives are paritioned and formatted, then you can navigate to them by doing something like `cd /media/USERNAME/LABEL` where USERNAME is your user name and LABEL is the label for the partition.

If your drives haven't been formatted, then you wouldn't see them in either location and you would instead want to look for `/dev/sd[a-z]`.  That is, you'd have an entry like `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`.  If they are partitioned, then you should also see `/dev/sda[0-9]` and `/dev/sdb[0-9]` (for example, `/dev/sda1`.)  But you'd have to at least format them before you can mount them and navigate to them...

If you haven't mounted the volumes, you can do it through nautilus by just clicking on the volume name.  Or from the terminal you can use `udisksctl`.  For example, I have a drive that is partitioned with just one file system.  The label of the drive is "d_extra".  I can view it in `/dev/disk/by-label`:

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-label
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 17 15:34 d_extra -> ../../sdb1
```

Then, once I know the name, I can mount it via `udisksctl` like so:

```
$ udisksctl mount -o noatime -b /dev/disk/by-label/d_extra
```

Then I can cd to it and view files:

```
$ cd /media/stephen/d_extra
$ ls
```

Answer (score -1):

On Linux you might have to login via terminal and use sudo. To go backwards you can use something like

```
cd down
cd Volumes/.../ 

//or

cd up
cd /.../Volumes
cd .../Volumes

//spaces in file name
cd /Volumes/My\Documents
```

FYI dev is your firmware and device files. On other Unix OSs' like Mac OS X they have created permission blocks on viewing those. Installing firmware from terminal is possible on Linux. Try not to tamper as your GUID may be stored there along with shadow hash files elsewhere in the file system and you don't want to create any open doors. Mac won't even allow output to text file. To help you understand the GUID hash being MD5 would take about three years to crack with 4 GBs of RAM. Its kind of serious.

Also try..

```
./Volumes/etc
```