# With 2 user accounts, what is the path to my HDD in Terminal?

Tags: command-line, hard-drive

About 8 hours ago, I asked this question and I got a great answer:
[In terminal, what is the path of my HDDs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649742/in-terminal-what-is-the-path-of-my-hdds)

- `/media/user1` was owned by *root*.
- `/media/user1/FooDrive` was owned by *user1*.

The answer to my first question was perfect. That is what I expected. But, that also seemed strange.

- I created a second user account, *user2*.
- `sudo ls -la /media/user1`
- `sudo ls -la /media`

**FooDrive** had disappeared.
There was no `/media/user2` directory.
Deleting the *user2* account did not make **FooDrive** appear again under `/media/user1` again.

What happens with regard to disk ownership, and the path to my disks, when there are 2 users?

Comment: Yes, you can by using `mount` command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I kind of new I needed to invest time to learn how to mount disks. But, I'm really more interested in the path to my disks with 2 user accounts. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click a drive in Nautilus, it automatically mounts to `/media/user1/FooDrive`. "user1" is the name of user you are logged with.

If you logout and login with another "user2", the drive will be still mount to the same place. And user2 will not see it.

You can fix this by running `sudo umount /media/user1/FooDrive` if this was the mount point.

Then if you click it again from user2, it will be mount to `/media/user2/FooDrive`.

You can always setup a permanent rule where to mount your drives in `/etc/fstab`. That is preferred if you have multiple drives and multiple users.

And you can always manually mount drives where you like by

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/user2/Foodrive
```

if your partition is `/dev/sdb1`. Instead of `/media/user2/Foodrive` you can use any other existing directory.

Comment: I'm new to Linux, so I'm more interested in understanding than fixing. After deleting user2, I now  just have 1 user account. I re-booted. There are still no disks under /media/user1, but the disk is accessible from the GUI interface. So, before I remount, where is my disk?

Comment: Did you click the disk in Nautilus? After you do it, it must be it /media/user1`. It does not mount automatically before you try to open it.

Comment: yes. It did remount. I think I get it now. That is very interesting. thank you.